# Есть ли переключение режимов в VS Code между ubuntu и виндой?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

Пытаюсь разобраться с VS codе. Подскажите кто работал с этим, есть ли режимы переключения между двумя операционками в нём? Т.е я осваиваю линукс, но в целом прицел на то, что GPT будет ментором в этом вопросе, однако в убунту расширения не хотят устанавливаться.

Comment: `не хотят устанавливаться` — слишком общее определение, название расширения, ошибки (сообщения) при установке и т.п., нужно больше подробностей

Comment: Спасибо за отклик. Я в принципе хотел уточнить — есть ли такая возможность. Без углубления причин) Если есть, то буду дальше копать.

Comment: Думаю что такой возможности нет, при установке `vscode` сам настраивает все что нужно для конкретной ОS переключать ничего не требуется, не могу себе представить такого рода переключатель или настройку. В любом случае если вы не находите ничего похожего в Settings то скорее всего этого нет.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ.